# Cannot convert string to a long in scala

Tags: scala

Why can I not convert the following string into a long? i am trying to do this in scala.

```
var a = "153978017952566571852"

val b = a.toLong
```

when I try to convert it I get the NumberFormatException

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because the number exceeds the limit of Long Integer which goes from *-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807*, with maximum of 19 digits, while your string contains 21 digits.

---

You can convert it to *Float* or *Double* if you don't have to be exact:

```
scala> val b = a.toFloat
b: Float = 1.5397802E20

scala> val b = a.toDouble
b: Double = 1.5397801795256658E20
```

Comment: You might also consider using a BigInt: `BigInt("153978017952566571852")`